# Nicescroll 3 - Vertical scroll after horizontal scrolling ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel, nicescroll

I'm trying to make a simple page where there are several rows of images, each one with a horizontal scrolling (using [Nicescroll 3](http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/)).

Using the mouse, when the horizontal scrolling of the row is finished, the mouse wheel has no function. What I wanted to do is that the page continued scrolling vertically after the horizontal scrolling has finished.

My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="square-container">
            <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- several other square-container divs -->
        <div class="square-container">
            <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- several other square-container divs -->
    </div>
    <!-- several other rows -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-content{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
#main-content > .row {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}    
.square-container {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 20px 30px 5px 30px;
}
.square{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1k1c3pq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for feedback.

Added to TODO list.

Issue opened -> https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/451